# find $y$ if $\sqrt[4]{y} + \sqrt[4]{16y} - 2 = 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attempt.

$\sqrt[4]{16y} = 2y$

so

$\sqrt[4]{y}+2y = 6$ after moving the constants.

I'm not too sure about this, but i think i can get rid of the radical by raising both sides of the equation to the 4th power?

$y+16y = 1,296$

After simplification I'm left with this.

$y = \frac{1,296}{17}$

Comment: $$\sqrt[4]{16y} = 2\sqrt[4]y$$

Comment: It is not true that $(16y)^{\frac{1}{4}}=2y$. It should be $2y^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Comment: If you raise both sides of the eqation $\sqrt[4]y+2y=6$ to the fourth power you obtain $y+8y\sqrt[4]{y^3}+24y^2\sqrt[4]{y^2}+32y^3\sqrt[4]y+16y^4=1296$. Then again, identity $\sqrt[4]{16y}=2y$ is not a thing, so whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recognize $\sqrt[4]{16}=2$ and simplify the equation

$$3\sqrt[4]{y}= 6$$

Then solve

$$y = 16$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = \sqrt[4]{y}$. Then your equation is equivalent to $$x+2x-2=4$$
Thus: $$3x = 6 \Rightarrow x = 2.$$ Now, we know $x = 2 = \sqrt[4]{y}$,so it follows $y = 16$.